# How to re-rendered the front-end after fetching data from API in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, rest

Could someone please tell me how to update my table entries after fetching the data from an API in? I have checked and see that the data arrived correctly and without any problem, but I can't get them to be reflected on my table except for last row. I know the design follow a very bad practice, I am planning to refactor it in time, but for the moment, I just want to learn how to update the table rows.

```
    axios.put(url_const, this.state)
      .then(respond => {
        const a = res.data.a;
        this.state.d = a;
        this.state.a = a;
        this.state.t = a.toString();
      });
  }
```

Comment: you can search for shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle and see it's examples to get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the state properly. In the sendArr(), instead of setting the array as

```
this.state.data = arr1;
```

set state using setState() like this:

```
this.setState({
  data: arr1,
  arr: arr1,
  text: arr1.toString()
```

})

The component will re-render itself automatically once the state is updated which in turn would show you the updated entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify state directly in react, but you should update a new state using this.setState

```
 axios.put(API_URL + "/1", this.state)
      .then(res => {
        const arr1 = res.data.arr;
        this.setState({
           data: arr1,
           arr: arr1,
           text: arr1.toString()
        })
      });
```

Also you should notice its a good practice to make your state as small as possible, you dont need to have data,arr, and text you only need (arr) one variable and you can induce the other variables from that variable (from arr in state)